# Encrypting file names

Tags: delphi

I need an encryption method that will encrypt (not encode) a file name so that the resulting encrypted string can be stored in a SQLite table.

The encryption method must not insert `#0` characters into the resulting TString (non ANSI).

Example:

- Before: `hello_world.txt`
- After: `y381a82jzseoi1`

The length of the two strings needs to be the same, or at least not more than 10-15% longer in length.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Consider reading [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) wikipedia article. If it don't apply to you then simply ignore my comment.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it like this:

1. Convert from text to binary using `TEncoding.GetBytes`. You'll need to decide on an encoding. To support Unicode UTF-8 or UTF-16 would be the most likely choices. Often UTF-8 is the most efficient in terms of space.
2. Encrypt using your chosen encryption algorithm. This converts the binary data returned by `TEncoding.GetBytes` into encrypted binary data.
3. Save the encrypted binary data to the database as a blob.

Note that I have avoided converting the encrypted binary data back to text. This deals with your desire to avoid null-terminators by simply side-stepping the issue. The key point for you to recognise is that encryption operates on binary data rather than text. It is an exceptionally common misconception that encryption algorithms operate on text.

If, for some reason that I do not anticipate, you simply must store the data as text, then you should encode it from binary to text. You could implement base255 encoding to avoid having null terminators, and keep the size down.